# mod_rewrite to split/strip URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

For a specific purpose, I need to be able to grab the first 2 paths from a URL to be used as username/md5sum'ed password - and the let the webserver handle the rest.

E.g: 
h..ps://192.168.5.6/*user*/*password*/                   -> should call /pkg/index.php?u=*user*&p=*password* 
h..ps://192.168.5.6/*user*/*password*/pack/*test.zip*      -> should call /pkg/pack/dl.php?u=*user*&p=*password*&f=*test.zip*

h..ps://192.168.5.6/*user*/*password*/images/default.png -> should call /pkg/images/default.png

/pkg/index.php might reference a bunch of other files located under /pkg - these URL's should not be modified..
I assume, that the original complete URI can be grabbed using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - and I from there can grab any parameters, that might have been passed in a get request to the original URL (h..ps://192.168.5.6/user/password/?parm1=x&parm2=y)

Of course, if no user/pass combination is given on the URL, it will just call h..ps://192.168.5.6/index.php

Can anyone tell me how to obtain this using mod_rewrite in Apache ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a file called ".htaccess" to the site's root directory and add this to the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /pkg/pack/dl.php?u=$1&p=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$ /pkg/pack/dl.php?u=$1&p=$2&f=$3
```

This turns on the mod_rewrite engine, then triggers silent rewrites (which won't modify the URL the visitor sees in their web browser) from a /user/pass/ pattern to the two-parameter version of your dl.php script, and from a /user/pass/file pattern to the three-parameter version of your dl.php script.

The above patterns allow letters, numbers, underscores and hyphens to appear in the username and password, and also periods to appear in the filename. Modify the pattern to allow additional or deny certain characters if necessary.